# Use UITabBarSystemItem icons with other buttons

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to use `UITabBarSystemItem` icons with other buttons (e.g. `UIButton`, `UIBarButtonItem`) just with code, that is, without using external images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this, by accessing `UITabBarItem` subviews and retrieving the `UIImageView` that contains the icon.

```
func getImageFrom(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem, blueColored: Bool) -> UIImage? {
    let tabBar = UITabBar()
    let item = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: tabBarSystemItem, tag: 0)
    tabBar.items = [item]
    if blueColored { // gray otherwise
        tabBar.selectedItem = item
    }
    let itemView = tabBar.subviews[0]
    let imageView = itemView.subviews[0] as? UIImageView
    //let label = itemView.subviews[1] as? UILabel // this is 'item' label
    return imageView?.image
}
```

Usage:

```
let buttonImage = getImageFrom(tabBarSystemItem: .more, blueColored: true)
```

It's worthy to mention that using icons improperly may violate iOS Human Interface Guidelines and cause your app to be rejected from App Store. [Read](http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/23/icon-fail/).